Can we use routes to re-prompt for an input in dialogflowCX?
I am trying to setup the date in my design, in such a way that if the date has already passed, then the user should be asked to enter the date again. I don't know if this possible with state handling as I'm using the condition: "$sys.func.IS_PAST_DATE($session.params.date-time) = true". So I'm using routes in such a way that if this condition is triggered, the user should come back to the same page and be prompted again. Can this problem be resolved without using webhooks? I am using the "date-time" parameter type for this.
I tried using routes but it shows the error: "You have reached the maximum allowed state machine execution steps. You may consider simplifying your agent/flow design", whenever I try this. if this can be done by state/event handling, what would be the steps? What event type will be used?

On that route if you set param date-time = null and then transition the route back to a page which collects required parameter of date-time you should be able to refill that session parameter.
The error message you are receiving indicates you are stuck in an infinite loop so your sys.func might be causing a loop if you are not nulling out the existing param and it is just ripping true true true all the way down. Also, make sure date-time is a system entity like @sys.date or similar.
